# Assigning values to 2d arrays without using index in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

As a challange I don't use array indexes to assigning or searching. What I want to do is reading characters from a text file and put them in an array that is 15x15. I created a 2d array using indexes but I couldn't do the assigning without them. I tried two things but I couldn't come up with a working idea. My code is basically like that:

```
        char **puzzleArray;
        puzzleArray = new char*[15];
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            puzzleArray[i] = new char[15];


        char *c;
        FILE* puzzle;
        puzzle = fopen("puzzle.txt", "r");


        for (int i=0; i < 15; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
                fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, puzzle);
                if (*c != ' ' && *c != '\n')
                    strcpy(*(puzzleArray + (i * 15)) + j , c);
                else
                    j--;
            }
```

I also tried assignin like this:

```
        char **puzzleArray;
        puzzleArray = new char*[15];
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            puzzleArray[i] = new char[15];


        char c;
        FILE* puzzle;
        puzzle = fopen("puzzle.txt", "r");


        for (int i=0; i < 15; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
                fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, puzzle);
                if (c != ' ' && c != '\n')
                    *(puzzleArray + (i * 15)) + j = c;
                else
                    j--;
            }
```

But none of them worked and when I do the second one compiler gives me the error "lvalue required as left operand of assignment".

Edit:
When I change the second code as:`

```
*(*(puzzleArray + (i * 15)) + j)
```

It compiled but when I tried to print the characters in array using this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    cout << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
        cout << *(*(puzzleArray + (i * 15)) + j);
}

//or using this

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    cout << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
        cout << puzzleArray[i][j];
}
```

It does not print characters and program crashes. In visual studio, it says an exception occurs at the assigning part.

Comment: type of `(puzzleArray + n)` is `char**` and type of  `*(puzzleArray + n)` is `char*`. You should not assign `char` to `char*`.

Comment: @c-smile It didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need nested allocations.
What's more, your code does not work because you assume your nested allocations will result in contiguous storage.

```
const int size = 15;
char* puzzleArray = new char[size*size];

// i'm not going to change file reading logic, 
// but it should be done better
// ideally by one read to a buffer
// Also the style seems like a bad mix of C and C++,
// but I can't do much about it with only this little fragment of code.
FILE* puzzle = fopen("puzzle.txt", "r");


for (int i=0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        char c;
        fread(&c, 1, 1, puzzle);
        if (c != ' ' && c != '\n')
            puzzleArray[i*size + j] = c;
        /* 
        // this does not seem right, i don't know what you're trying to do here
        // i'm gonna assume that you want to move to the next line
        else
            j--;
        */
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, right. I forgot that new allocates memories seperately if I do it with this way. Thank you. By the way, "j--" is for don't leave any blank space in array.

Comment: The memory does not have to be continuous. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @CSPei having discontinuity in this example only makes for more allocations, only bad things.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems for your second try.  And whether the memory is continous or not is not relevant. You can still use 2D array and using nested allocations. 
(note that, although somebody downvoted my answer, but I think he/she did it wrong).

Here is the fully tested code using 2D array and nested memory allocations.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    int main() {
        using namespace std;
        char **puzzleArray;
        puzzleArray = new char*[15];
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            puzzleArray[i] = new char[15];

        char c;
        FILE* puzzle;
        puzzle = fopen("puzzle.txt", "r");


        for (int i=0; i < 15; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; ) {
                fread(&c, sizeof(char), 1, puzzle);
                if (c != ' ' && c != '\n') {
                    *(*(puzzleArray + i) + j) = c; // you can see the difference if you compare with your original code.
                    ++j;
                }
            }
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; ++j) {
                cout << puzzleArray[i][j]; // you could use pointer arithmatic here too. using index is just convenient to show the result.
            }
            cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it should compile. what did you get?

Comment: It compiled but when I want to print them program crashes. I printed using both pointer arithmetic and array indexes to check. None of them works.

Comment: I guess we are getting closer :) I tried, it worked but in Dev C++, it crashed after printed the first row, in visual studio , it wrote meaningles symbols after first row. But I guess this is because of something else. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This approach won't work because the storage is not contiguous.

Comment: @Sopel, I guess you down voted my answer. But I don't think you are right here. Please review my updated code. Thanks.

Comment: Now it's fine, but it wasn't